# I am trying to send an email based on which category something falls into (mgr, str, wtr), but it only sends to the first email in the group?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, range, conditional-statements, email

I have been slaving over this piece of code and the script is saying that it's working, the Logger.log, is popping up after every line, but it's only using on of the emails to send the emails to regardless of category. I have tried many different solutions, but I think I need some help (I've searched online forEVER and still can't find anything to help for this problem).
Here's my code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetProgressReport = ss.getSheetByName("ProgressReport");
  var sheetManagers = ss.getSheetByName("Managers");
  var range = sheetProgressReport.getRange(4, 7, sh.getLastRow(), 1);
  var rangeSentEmail = sheetProgressReport.getRange(4, 8, sh.getLastRow(), 1);
  var column = range.getColumnIndex();
      if(column === 7) {
  var managerEmail = sheetManagers.getRange(22, 2).getValue().toString(); //object to string with respective manager's email
  var strategistEmail = sheetManagers.getRange(23, 2).getValue().toString(); //object to string with respective strategist's email
  var writerEmail = sheetManagers.getRange(24, 2).getValue().toString(); //object to string with respective writer's email
  var client = sheetManagers.getRange(2, 2).getValue().toString(); //object to string with client name
        var message = "Please tell Jordan if you get this! Thank you! :)"; //string with message
  var category = range.getValues();
  var columnSentEmail = rangeSentEmail.getValues();
        var mgr = "mgr";
        var str = "str";
        var wtr = "wtr";
        var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";
         if (columnSentEmail != EMAIL_SENT && category === "") {email = "";}
                        else if (category = mgr) {email = managerEmail;}
                        else if (category = str) {email = strategistEmail;}
                        else if (category = wtr) {email = writerEmail;}
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, client, message);
   rangeSentEmail.setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
   }
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with the way that I'm processing (or the lack of processing) the data in the "rangeSentEmail/range" vars.
Here's my goal if you can't tell from the messy code:
I want to read the top 5-10 lines in the "rangeSentEmail/range" vars, then check to make sure that "rangeEmailSent" is not marked with "EMAIL_SENT"; if it meets that requirement, then I want the "range" column to check for labels (mgr, wtr, str) and then send emails to the respective "managerEmail, writerEmail, or strategistEmail" based on which label is in the column.
I honestly can't deduce where the problem is, so PLEASE and THHHAAANNKK YOUUUU in advance! I'll be checking up regularly for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here
    var category = range.getValues()

change from getValues() to getValue(). The first is returing an array of objects and the second return only the value, be sure that is a single value.

The second problem is here:

```
 if (columnSentEmail != EMAIL_SENT && category === "") {email = "";}
                    else if (category = mgr) {email = managerEmail;}
                    else if (category = str) {email = strategistEmail;}
                    else if (category = wtr) {email = writerEmail;}
```

Try using only "==" to compare values.  The operator "===" forces you to check if the value AND type are identical and using only one equals "=" just attribute the value to the category variable. So, use only "==" to make this comparisons.

Best,

Comment: I JUST got done talking with one of my buddies who knows javascript pretty well and he pointed this out to me. THANK YOU so much "br araujo" for getting back to me!! This was EXACTLY what the problem was!! I appreciate your help ten-fold! If you ever need something engineered--that isn't script work-- I've got your back! Also, would you be able to tell me where I could go to learn more of the basics? I feel like every time I try and write a script or code at all, I end up messing something elementary up like .getValue vs. .getValues or the = vs. == vs. ===

Comment: @JordanH this is an excelent course of javascript http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript